# Remove the duplicate element From the array through map in swift

Tags: swift

I got error

> Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

I have a array as shown below and I want to remove the duplicate element to get a new array without any duplicacy , My code of swift is :-

```
let oldArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,91,2,3,6]
var newArray = oldArray.map( $0 != $1)
print(newArray)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Besides the bad syntax, the `map` closure only has one argument, not two.

Comment: @rmaddy  I am new to swift please let me know how can I do so using map and filter

Comment: You can't use `map` for this. `map` is for transforming the values of the array into different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let newArray = Array(Set(oldArray))
```

**OR**

```
let oldArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,91,2,3,6]
var newArray = [Int]()
oldArray.forEach {
    if !newArray.contains($0) {
        newArray.append($0)
    } 
}
print(newArray)
```

Comment: This would be extremely inefficient for larger collections. Better to use a set and filter only the objects that are actually inserted

Comment: @LeoDabus i added the other way to clarify that to the op , he has to use option #1